# Trouble understanding DatePicker for Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, datepicker, phonegap-plugins

Need help implementing this DatePicker plugin for Phonegap. Maybe I'm missing something here, but I am totally lost as to what to do after adding the plugin to my project via CLI. The documented "usage" is not helping me out whatsoever.

With the following example html, what should be added for its hook?

```
<form>
    <label for="user_name">Name</label>
        <input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="Name" />
    <!-- what here?? -->
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

And using jQuery, how would I initialize it?

**Repository:** https://github.com/nicholasareed/cordova-plugin-datepicker/tree/007feae6393d7022af51d9a60055f7de4dd89e54

Thank you in advance for any information helping me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to add servicing of your input. Usually you do it in separate *.js file.

Create test.js file in your project's www catalog and add it to youd index.html head section:

```
<html> 
    <head>
     ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-test/test.js">
</head>

    <body> 
     ...
    </body>
```

In your test.js file add datePicker configuration:

```
var options = {
  date: new Date(),
  mode: 'date'
};
```

and onClick event handler (jQuerMobile example):

```
$('#idButton').on('click',function(){
    // show picker
    datePicker.show(options, function(date){
    //get result
        alert("date result " + date);  
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific form element I should use, or will it simply override any element I place there with that id? Also, when using CLI, would I still need to manually call it in my config.xml?

Comment: it only handles event. Just put id of any element, when you click it, date picker will be shown and result will be stored in date variable. No need in adding to config file. Instead of CLI you could also put datepicker lib in js file and declare it in <head> but it doesnt really matter how you add it.

Answer (score 2):

All modern phones (Android / iPhone) have support for the HTML5 input types. This will trigger the native date-selection. No need for complex datepicker-jquery-javascript magic anymore. Just try this:

```
<input type="date" name="mydate" />
```

And click the textfield on your phone.

Comment: Oh that's nice! Thank you for this. Could have saved me hours of Googling.